# ReactJS migration legacy URLs practice?

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, url, redirect

I'm migrating the front-end of a web application to React.

The site has around 90k old 301 redirects URLs that i need to handle but I'm not sure to how to handle them and I'm a bit stuck in the googling process of it.

The old URLs is not following any pattern at all, what is the best practice to handle them so they get redirected/route them to right page?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a redirect on the server side (in server.js) based on a match on a json.

Using: res.redirect('url');